# JQuery mobile listview - use images from Android sdcard?

Tags: android, image, cordova

Is this possible - I mean to use images saved to the sdcard as thumbnails in a JQuery mobile listview? I cannot find anything on this... essentially I think the question can be boiled down to: is it possible to use images stored on the sdcard as the src attribute in an img tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You have to use file:// to access the file. E.g.

```
...src="file:///sdcard/image.png" ...
```

EDIT:

In fact, to ease portability, you should use cordova's [File](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) API to obtain a reference to the Sd Card file system.

Comment: Wow - thanks so much. If that works, I'' be amazed. Been trying to get info on this for a few days... maybe I never asked correctly. Anyway, I am using the File API already, and have a ref to the sdcard so hopefully this will be cake. Will let you know.